# LoggingFilter in 2.21.0 of GeoServer - lack of default constructor

Tags: geoserver, logging

In version of GeoServer 2.20.4 I could use filter under web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Request Logging Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enabled</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log-request-headers</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log-request-bodies</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

In 2.21.0 default constructor (empty) has been gone and I need to pass some `GeoServer` object.

```
 public LoggingFilter(GeoServer geoServer) {
        this.geoServer = geoServer;
    }
```

Could you tell me how can I use this filter properly now, in 2.21.0 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.21.0 the logging filter is configured directly from the Web UI, no need to restart GeoServer anymore.

[Check out the documentation.](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#internal-settings)

Comment: So I can remove this filter completely?

Comment: Yes, it can be removed fully.